# PostGIS st_centroid but return as kml

Tags: postgis

SELECT
st_centroid(the_geom), roads."id" FROM
"public".roads

How would I do the centroid but return it as kml?
basically I want the center of the line string cords and the name of the road.
And is there a way to return lat long of the road centroid as x & y

Answer (score 4):

SELECT ST_AsKML(ST_Centroid(the_geom)),id FROM roads